# Obtener datos de un array con facade DB en laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, depuración

Estimados tengo la siguiente consulta realizada con laravel

```
$datos = DB::table('mandato')
->join('compromiso_pago','mandato.CP_IdCompromisoPago','=','compromiso_pago.IdCompromisoPago')
->join('unidad_recaudadora','compromiso_pago.UR_IdUnidadRecaudadora','=','unidad_recaudadora.IdUnidadRecaudadora')
->join('tipo_recaudacion','compromiso_pago.TR_IdTipoRecaudacion','=','tipo_recaudacion.IdTipoRecaudacion')
->join('aporte','tipo_recaudacion.IdTipoRecaudacion','=','aporte.TR_IdTipoRecaudacion')
->where([
['unidad_recaudadora.Nombre','like','%'.$clave.'%'],
['unidad_recaudadora.D_IdDiocesis','=',10],
['compromiso_pago.TR_IdTipoRecaudacion','=',$idTipoRecaucadion->IdTipoRecaudacion]
])
->whereColumn('aporte.UR_IdUnidadRecaudadora','unidad_recaudadora.IdUnidadRecaudadora')
->groupBy('unidad_recaudadora.IdUnidadRecaudadora','unidad_recaudadora.CodMandatoAccess','compromiso_pago.TR_IdTipoRecaudacion','aporte.PorcentajeParroquial','tipo_recaudacion.Comision')
->select('unidad_recaudadora.IdUnidadRecaudadora','unidad_recaudadora.CodMandatoAccess','compromiso_pago.TR_IdTipoRecaudacion','aporte.PorcentajeParroquial','tipo_recaudacion.Comision')->first();
```

Luego de la variable datos asigno un valor a otra variable de esta manera:

```
$porcentajeParroquial = $datos->PorcentajeParroquial;
$comision = $datos->Comision;
$codigocorto = $datos->CodMandatoAccess;
```

pero al hacerlo asi me da el siguiente error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero por alguna razon cuando uso la funcion de laravel DD() si me obtiene el resultado:

```
$porcentajeParroquial = $datos->PorcentajeParroquial;
dd($porcentajeParroquial);
$comision = $datos->Comision;
$codigocorto = $datos->CodMandatoAccess;
```

me imprime lo siguiente que seria el valor del porcentaje

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De igual manera subo un print de la variables $datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Actualización]

Se me olvido comentar que estoy realizando un foreach y que se realiza una transaccion a la base de datos por cada iteracion

Comment: pero tu erro no es en `$porcentajeParroquial` si no en : `$datos->PorcentajeParroquial`

Comment: exacto, pero si te das cuenta por alguna razon al depurar si obtiene el dato, remplaza dd($porcentajeParroquial) por dd($datos->PorcentajeParroquial) y el resultado es el mismo, la diferencia es que sin dd()  se cae

Comment: Porque no mejor muestras un dd() de $datos

Comment: actualizado estimado

Comment: segun tu actualizacion lo correcto es: `$porcentajeParroquial = $datos[0]->PorcentajeParroquial;` o por el contrario : `$porcentajeParroquial = $datos[0]["PorcentajeParroquial"];` y asi con el resto

Answer (score 1):

Estoy en un celular por lo que no puedo ver pero según lo que entiendo no estás accediendo a un objeto sino aún Array

Recuerda lo básico de php, si tú colección de datos es un objeto (object) puedes entrar a sus propiedades con

```
(->) "la flechita"
```

Si tú colección es un Array puedes entrar a las propiedades con

```
([ ]) "Corchetes"
```

Una forma sencilla de ver de qué tipo de colección se trata si no sabes es hacer

```
var_dum($variables);

die();


O 



print_r($variable);

exit();
```

Tu línea de código queda de la siguiente forma.

```
$vaiable = $datos['dato espesifico'];
```

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración estimado, la verdad es que lo sabia pero no de manera conceptual como usted me lo indica, el problema es que me devuelve un objeto y no un array y al querer extraer el valor con flechita "->" me dice que no existe el valor

Answer (score 1):

Luego de tanto analizar e investigar por internet conceptos tecnicos, el motivo por el cual la funcion no llegaba al objetivo es porque en un universo de 200 iteraciones 8 de ellas venian empty y al momento de asociarse se caia al no encontrar la referencia (y se caia porque no se estaba validando), la manera en que me di cuenta fue la siguiente

```
$a = [];
foreach ($NombresArray as $clave => $valor) {
    $datos = DB::table('mandato')
                                ->join('compromiso_pago','mandato.CP_IdCompromisoPago','=','compromiso_pago.IdCompromisoPago')
                                ->join('unidad_recaudadora','compromiso_pago.UR_IdUnidadRecaudadora','=','unidad_recaudadora.IdUnidadRecaudadora')
                                ->join('tipo_recaudacion','compromiso_pago.TR_IdTipoRecaudacion','=','tipo_recaudacion.IdTipoRecaudacion')
                                ->join('aporte','tipo_recaudacion.IdTipoRecaudacion','=','aporte.TR_IdTipoRecaudacion')
                                ->where([
                                    ['unidad_recaudadora.Nombre','like','%'.$clave.'%'],
                                    ['unidad_recaudadora.D_IdDiocesis','=',10],
                                    ['compromiso_pago.TR_IdTipoRecaudacion','=',$idTipoRecaucadion->IdTipoRecaudacion]
                                ])
                                ->whereColumn('aporte.UR_IdUnidadRecaudadora','unidad_recaudadora.IdUnidadRecaudadora')
                                ->groupBy('unidad_recaudadora.IdUnidadRecaudadora','unidad_recaudadora.CodMandatoAccess','compromiso_pago.TR_IdTipoRecaudacion','aporte.PorcentajeParroquial','tipo_recaudacion.Comision')
                                ->select('unidad_recaudadora.IdUnidadRecaudadora','unidad_recaudadora.CodMandatoAccess','compromiso_pago.TR_IdTipoRecaudacion','aporte.PorcentajeParroquial','tipo_recaudacion.Comision')->get();


                    $datos = $datos->toArray();
                    array_push($a,$datos);
                }
                dd($a);
```

Saludos, espero sirva a futuro